# The orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement from "Linear Algebra Done Right"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, orthogonality

The following content is from "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler

> **Corollary:** Suppose $U$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$. Then $$U = (U ^\perp)^\perp.$$
>   We need to prove the following: i) $U \subseteq (U^\perp)^\perp$ and 
>    ii) $(U^\perp)^\perp \subseteq U$

Proof i): Supposer $u \in U$. Then $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$ for $v \in U^\perp$. Since all vector $u$ is orthogonal to $v$. Then $u \in U$. Hence $u \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$

I do understand the proof for i) as stated in the above.

But I'm confused about the proof in ii)

ii) Let $u \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$ From Proposition 2, we have that $V = U \bigoplus U^\perp$. and so $u$ can be written as $u=v+w$ where $v \in U$ and $w \in U^\perp$. But $u - v = w$, so $u - v \in U^\perp$.

Now we already have that $u \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$ and $v \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$ and $u - v \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$. Therfore, $u - v \in U ^\perp \cap (U^\perp)^\perp$.

***Here is where I don't understand! Why we can let $u = v + w$, but since $u \in (U ^\perp)^\perp$? and Why does $u - v \in U ^\perp \cap (U^\perp)^\perp$?

Comment: Since $u - v \in U ^\perp  $ and $u - v \in   (U^\perp)^\perp$, it follows that $u - v \in U^\perp \cap (U^\perp)^\perp$

Comment: Thanks! I got how $u - v \in U^\perp \cap (U^\perp)^\perp$ work right now. But I don't get why we can let $u = v + w$, but since $u \in (U^\perp)^\perp$

Comment: Wait, how is $U \oplus U^\perp = V$ ? How is $U^\perp$ even a subspace of $V$? Are we in an inner product space?

Comment: You should declare what $V$ is, and in particular what $U^\perp$ is. I suspect you mean $V$ to be an inner product space over real or complex numbers, and $U^\perp$ to be the orthogonal complement, but in general, $U^\perp$  may either not make sense, or $(U^\perp)^\perp$ may be *much* bigger than $U$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $V=U\oplus U^\perp$, *every* vector in $V$ can be written as a sum of a vector in $U$ and a vector in $U^\perp$.

This holds, in particular, for $u\in(U^\perp)^\perp$. So, according to Axler, write
$$
u=v+w,\qquad v\in U, w\in U^\perp
$$
Now apply the assumption that $u\in(U^\perp)^\perp$ and the fact that $v\in U\subseteq(U^\perp)^\perp$ to conclude that
$$
w=u-v\in(U^\perp)^\perp
$$
as well. On the other hand, $w\in U^\perp$ by hypothesis. Therefore
$$
w=u-v\in U^\perp\cap(U^\perp)^\perp
$$
A general result about orthogonal complements is that, for every subspace $X$, $X\cap X^\perp=\{0\}$. This holds in particular for $X=U^\perp$.

Hence $w=u-v=0$, so $u=v\in U$.

Comment: Since $V = U \oplus U^\perp$, then U is a subspace of vector space V. But why does $u \in (U^\perp)^\perp$ be equal to V, Since $u = v + w$?

Comment: @Algorisum $u$ is an element of $V$. *Every* element of $V$ can be written as $v+w$ for some $v\in U$ and $w\in U^\perp$.

Comment: Yes.... I forget about that. Thank you

Comment: @egreg is $(U^\perp)^\perp \subseteq U$ in general? Or is the opposite true in general?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso In general $U\subseteq U^{\perp\perp}$; equality holds in finite dimensional spaces; in Hilbert spaces it holds only for closed subspaces.